# The Solr server could not be reached. Further data is therefore unavailable

Tags: search

I have installed a solr 5.2.1 in my windows 7 and I have created a solr core through SOLR Admin UI. It works fine. When, I trying to connect to solr by help of search_api_solr module in drupal 7.38 on my local host, The following error is coming.

"The Solr server could not be reached. Further data is therefore unavailable". What I have missed out, Anyone can Please help. Refer the below images.

[image: Search Api Server Edit screen]

[image: After edited the server name]

Comment: is this port open? If you connect using telnet, what do you see? Is Solr process working? Can you connect using any client other than Drupal?..

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your path for solr is wrong. If you setup solr by drupal instructions then your solr path must be:
/solr/drupal